# Is any of this PHP code vulnerable to arbitrary file upload?

Tags: php, security, upload

I have two files. One for uploading an image via file, and another for uploading an image via url. Is there any way of bypassing the checks to be able to perform arbitrary file upload?

Here is the code for uploading locally:
http://pastebin.com/8LFiA6K9

Here is code for uploading via url:
http://pastebin.com/MTVXMKyz

I get an invalid url error for non-image files, so I assume its somewhat safe. And I also assume the regex check in the first file is safe too.

Comment: this should be on code review

Answer (score 0):

Your second script is vulnerable to arbitrary file upload as one can upload any file with any file name extension, including `.php`, as long as the content is recognized as valid image. You should validate the file name extension similar to how you do it in your first script.

Furthermore, your second script is also vulnerable to SQL injection via `$_REQUEST["subject"]` and `$_POST["pmcat_id"]`.